# Ending a Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.2, I'm writing up a basic menu program, and when the option to quit is entered, the function is not ending.
When quit is chosen, it ends the loop the rest of the script is in, and should terminate the script, but it isn't, for whatever reason?
Am I missing an 'end' function that kills the script, or is the new Python Shell just buggy?
Pretty sure this wasn't necessary in Python 2.7.

```
import random
choice = str(input("\nMenu:\n(I)nstructions\n(C)alculate blah\n(Q)uit\n>>>"))
while choice != "q" or choice != "Q":
    while choice != "i" and choice != "I" and choice != "c" and choice != "C" and choice != "q" and choice != "Q":
        print("Invalid menu choice.")
        choice = str(input("\nMenu:\n(I)nstructions\n(C)alculate blah\n(Q)uit\n>>>"))
    if choice == "i" or choice == "I":
        print("blahblah.")
        choice = str(input("\nMenu:\n(I)nstructions\n(C)alculate blah\n(Q)uit\n>>>"))   
    if choice == "c" or choice == "C":
        x = int(input("Please enter the number of x: "))
        while x < 0:
            x = int(input("Please enter the number of x: "))
        y = int(input("Please enter the number of y: "))
        while y < 0:
            y = int(input("Please enter the number of y: "))
        z = str(input("blah (B) or (P) z?: "))
        while z != "b" and z != "p" and z != "B" and z != "P":
            z = str(input("blah (B) or (P) z?: "))
        if z == "b" or z == "B":
            total = x*10 + y*6 + 0
            print("blah $", total, " blah ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
        #function that outputs the cost of premium z
        if z == "p" or z == "P":
            luck = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
            if luck == 10:
                total = x*10 + y*6
                print("\nblah$", total, " blah z for ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
            #below is the normal function, for when the customer is not a lucky winner
            if luck != 10:
                total = x*12.50 + y*7.50
                print("blah $", total, " blah ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
        choice = str(input("\nMenu:\n(I)nstructions\n(C)alculate\n(Q)uit\n>>>"))
```

Comment: Nothing can be said without seeing the code.

Comment: If you want the script to exit, you can use `sys.exit(0)`, but yes, show the code if you want any more specific help.

Comment: pastebin.com/Ww4auw7E I couldn't think of an upload site I could trust, but here's a pastebin of the code. It's nothing at all complex, just trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness of my question, I'm just confused, as I've never seen this behaviour before. I've indented all my code correctly, I've been through python documentation, my textbooks, google, et al.
Couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Epidemic ...and you think pastebin.com is trustworthy?! They're chock full of intrusive ads; consider gist.github.com (or another non-ad-supported pastebin) in the future.

Comment: ...by the way, it's generally polite to post the smallest code sample necessary to reproduce the problem, ie. removing irrelevant bits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is suggesting that you post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)s - "Short, self-contained, correct examples".

Comment: Yes, I probably should have done that.
Pastebin was the quickest I could find, and I don't mind ad-supported sites provided the ads aren't insanely obtrusive.
Github had completely slipped my mind, and I was trying to think of it. Brainfart, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
while choice != "q" or choice != "Q":    # this should be "and"!
```

always returns `True`, creating an infinite loop.

Also, you've got quite a convoluted bit of logic here. This can be simplified a lot:

```
import random
while True:
    choice = str(input("\nMenu:\n(I)nstructions\n(C)alculate blah\n(Q)uit\n>>>")).lower()
    if choice == "i":
        print("blahblah.")
        continue
    elif choice == "q":
        break
    elif choice == "c":
        while True:
            x = int(input("Please enter the number of x: "))
            if x >= 0: break
        while True:
            y = int(input("Please enter the number of y: "))
            if y >= 0: break
        while True:
            z = str(input("blah (B) or (P) z?: ")).lower()
            if z in "bp": break
        if z == "b":
            total = x*10 + y*6 + 0
            print("blah $", total, " blah ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
        #function that outputs the cost of premium z
        else:  # z must be "p"
            luck = random.randrange(1, 11, 1)
            if luck == 10:
                total = x*10 + y*6
                print("\nblah$", total, " blah z for ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
            #below is the normal function, for when the customer is not a lucky winner
            if luck != 10:
                total = x*12.50 + y*7.50
                print("blah $", total, " blah ", x, " x and ", y, " y. blah!")
    else:
        print("Invalid menu choice.")
        continue
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ww4auw7E
I couldn't think of an upload site I could trust, but here's a pastebin of the code.
It's nothing at all complex, just trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Now that I've managed to get IDLE running again (It refuses to run code on occasion, not entirely sure why), it all works.
Thank you very mych, @TimPietzcker

Answer (score 1):

One way to perform quit operations in Python is to throw a custom exception and catch that exception explicitly. Please correct me if I am wrong, AFAIK this doesn't put a big over-head on your python program. It could done as simple as the what I show below:

```
...
class QuitException(Exception);
...
def MyMenuProgram():
    ...
    ...
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        MyMenuProgram()
    catch QuitException:
        pass
    catch Exception, e:
        raise
```

Comment: `sys.exit()` already throws a `SystemExit` exception; why would you create a new one to do the same thing?

Comment: Like I said, `correct me if I am wrong` :). Thanks for that info. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Redacted - `input()` is indeed the way to get user input in Py3k. Another of the glorious differences between Python 2.7 and Python 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim answered, your loop condition is wrong.

```
while choice != "q" or choice != "Q":
```

Let's take a look at this, logically:

1. if choice == "q", choice != "Q", loop condition evaluates to `false or true`, which is `true`
2. if choice == "Q", choice != "q", loop condition evaluates to `true or false`, which is `true`
3. if choice != "q" or "Q", loop condition evaluates to `true or true`, which is `true`

You need to change this loop condition to:

```
while choice != "q" and choice != "Q":
```

or

```
while choice.lower() != "q":
```

Comment: I would actually go further and suggest `while choice[0].lower() != 'q'` so that the user input `quit` is correctly handled.

Comment: @Li-aungYip, I don't believe the OP actually meant that the user would input 'quit', I think that was just poorly worded. However, in the case that that input is expected, you are entirely correct.

Comment: Defensive coding is (nearly) never a bad idea.

Comment: @Li-AungYip and I have been chatting through an IRC net, we know each other IRL. Now that I've done the code to-spec, I'm going to do the task the way I would do it, without constraints.